# Okhttp dns over https

Tags: android, okhttp

This my code

```
package com.example.myapplication

import android.webkit.WebView

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient

class CustomWebViewClient(private val okHttpClient: OkHttpClient) : android.webkit.WebViewClient() {

    override fun shouldInterceptRequest(

        view: WebView?,

        request: android.webkit.WebResourceRequest?

    ): android.webkit.WebResourceResponse? {

        // Use custom OkHttpClient for loading resources

        return okHttpClient.newCall(

            okhttp3.Request.Builder()

                .url(request?.url.toString())

                .build()

        ).execute().body?.byteStream()?.let {

            android.webkit.WebResourceResponse(null, null, it)

        }

    }

}
```

Can't load JavaScript resources
Page loading but some JavaScript function like disable

Note I'm already set enabled JavaScript true in main activity

It's successful to connect with doh the only problem is some website can't load JavaScript properly.